# Python not running from terminal

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, windows-store

I already have 2 versions of python installed on my windows, and the interpreters work well, but when I try to run python from cmd or PowerShell, I'm asked to get python again from windows store, how do I fix this

I opened cmd and PowerShell and typed python expecting it to open the python interpreter and I made a .py text file and typed python the name of the file in cmd expecting it to run the program

Comment: try `python3` instead of `python`. if it doesn't work, check `PATH`.

Comment: Could you edit the post to include the commands you ran? If you don't remember run the `history` command to see.

Comment: @JayPeerachai its actually in `python` in windows & `python3` on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add python path to the path on the environment variables.
What you should do:

1. Right click "my computer"
2. Go to "properties"
3. click on "advanced system settings"
4. Go to "environment variables"
5. On system Variables look for "path" (if there isn't one create one)
6. Click on "path" and click on "Edit"
7. Now you should click on "new" and paste your python folder path
8. Click "OK" and everything should be working just fine now

I used to have this problem before and after following this steps it started working.